# Android getAssets.open() vs Java File method, log printing String issues

Tags: java, android, file, binaryfiles

I am parsing a binary file. I didn't face any problem while doing it in java,

```
File file= new File("c:/xyz.bin");
DataInputStream di= new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
BufferedInputStream bin= new BufferedInputStream(dataIStream);
byte[] byteArray= new byte[bin.available()];
bin.read(byteArray);
```

And I am parsing the "byteArray" according to my needs using my parserClass.
Assigning the sub-bytes to different byte array members of the class "someClass", and while printing Using custom Converter to convert byte array to String.

```
System.out.println("Name: "+Converter.String(
        someClass.getFileName()));
System.out.println("Num: "+someClass.getInteger());
```

Name: FILENAME
Num: 2

Everything is working fine.

But when I tried it in Android:

```
String fileName= "xyz.bin";
InputStream in= getAssets().open(fileName);
BufferedInputStream bin= new BufferedInputStream(new DataInputStream(in));
byte[] byteArray= new byte[bin.available()];
bin.read(byteArray);
```

I am using the same parser.
I am facing problem in getting the values and printing it in the log like..

```
String name = Converter.String(someClass.getFileName())
Log.i("File name: ", name);
Log.i("Number: ", String.valueOf(someClass.getInteger()));
```

This is from the log that I am getting
File name: ����������������
Number: 0

Is it because getAssets.open() treats a binary file differently? I don't see what went wrong. The only difference betwwen the two codes is, in java I am using "File" and in Android I am using "getAssets.open()" methods.